# ¿Como añado datos a un archivo sin reemplzar el existente? En C

Tags: c

Es la primera vez que hago una pregunta aquí asi que espero formularla correctamente

Estoy haciendo un programa para reemplazar datos y añadir también.

Logre hacer que reemplace el texto en caso de necesitarlo pero no logro encontrar la manera de añadir nuevos datos dentro de un offset
¿Como hago que al escribir el archivo no se sobreescriban datos existentes si no que lo añada a la ubicación actual y mueva el dato a la siguiente ubicación?

Lo que intento es
Que en vez de cas123va sea casa123nova dentro del archivo abierto

EDITO: A lo mejor lo planteo mal y para ese tipo de cosas es mejor crear otro archivo vació copiar la información poco a poco y vaya rellenándose según la situación lo requiera y luego reemplazar el original.

Le doy muchas vueltas y busco pero no veo que nadie haya intentado en vez de sustituir datos, añadir datos en la posición que se le indique

Comment: Hola Maou, un archivo no es mas que una secuencia/flujo unidimensional de bytes, modificar un byte de la secuencia es simple, pero insertar requiere siempre "desplazar" todos los bytes después del punto de inserción.  Si posicionas el cursor de escritura en la posición de inserción que te interesa y escribes dos bytes lo que haces no es insertar dos nuevos bytes, sino que reemplazas los dos bytes existentes a partir del cursor por los nuevos,

Comment: Por lo tanto siempre que tengas que modificar un archivo agregando bytes en una posición que no sea el final del mismo necesitaras de alguna estructura temporal para almacenar al menos los datos que hay a partir del punto de inserción de forma temporal para poder luego agregarlos tras los nuevos datos insertados, puede ser otro archivo temporal, un buffer en memoria, etc, dependiendo del caso puede resultar mas eficiente o adecuado una cosa u otra.

Answer (score 0):

No puedes. Al escribir un archivo en realidad lo estás sobreescribiendo, a menos que lo hagas al final.

Incluso cuando trabajas con la **memoria RAM** sucede algo similar; no aparece más mágicamente. Si tienes un arreglo de 10 elementos y quieres agregar otro más, necesitas reservar más. Lo que puede cambiar es la manera en que agregas el elemento.

Por ejemplo, si trabajas con una **lista enlazada** solo necesitas modificar algunos punteros dependiendo donde quieras colocar el elemento. Pero si trabajas con un **arreglo** (todos los elementos están en posiciones contiguas de memoria), necesariamente tienes que copiar y/o desplazar todos los elementos cada vez que quieras aumentar su tamaño o insertar un elemento.

---

No hay otra opción. De forma similar al ejemplo de la memoria RAM, solo puedes sobrescribir la información sabiamente.

Considera el siguiente plan para *insertar* información en una posición arbitraria:

- Abre el archivo en modo de lectura/escritura.
- Guarda una copia desde la posición en que quieres *insertar* hasta el final del archivo.
- Escribe la información nueva.
- Al final de la anterior, colocas la copia que hiciste.

En código, se vería más o menos así:

```
const char *insertar = "información para insertar";
FILE* file = fopen("archivo", "r+");

// Ir al final del archivo para averiguar su tamaño
fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);
int fileSize = ftell(file);

// Calcular el tamaño de la información que se debe conservar y reservar 
la memoria suficiente
int backupSize = fileSize - position;
char* backup = malloc(backupSize * sizeof(char));

// Crear la copia
fseek(file, position, SEEK_SET);
fread(backup, sizeof(char), backupSize, file);

// Insertar la información nueva y restaurar la copia
fseek(file, position, SEEK_SET);
fwrite(insertar, sizeof(char), strlen(insertar), file);
fwrite(backup, sizeof(char), backupSize, file);

// Liberar memoria y cerrar archivo
free(backup);
fclose(file);
```

Otra posibilidad es cargar el archivo completo en memoria RAM, realizar todas las modificaciones ahí y guardarlas en el archivo cuando termines de trabajar.